# Where to disable UAC on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

They say the following [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/cbebc83f-7a4e-4cc5-b13c-13cf21c6ad25/):

> > We found that we had to disable UAC, reboot and then we were able to apply the permissions."

I have run `msconfig` but I can't see where I can disable UAC.

Comment: Do you not see a 'Tools' tab in msconfig? There you should see an option to change UAC settings.

Answer (score 7):

To turn off UAC:

1. Click **Start**, and then click **Control Panel**.
2. In Control Panel, click **User Accounts**.
3. In the User Accounts window, click **User Accounts**.
4. In the User Accounts tasks window, click **Turn User Account Control on or off**.
5. If UAC is currently configured in Admin Approval Mode, the User Account Control message appears. Click **Continue**.
6. **Clear** the Use User Account Control (UAC) to help protect your computer **check box**, and then click **OK**.
7. Click **Restart Now** to apply the change right away, or click Restart Later, and then close the User Accounts tasks window.

[More info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_S3)

Variation in Recent 2008 R2:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bart's answer describes how to turn off UAC.  [On the server, it really isn't a bad idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/43706/is-disabling-uac-on-a-windows-2008-server-a-bad-idea), unless you are using the server as a desktop or utility machine.

One thing not mentioned is that some applications may need to be re-installed after the change, because it does change some pretty central things in the OS.

Also, you do *not* want go back and forth with it. Don't turn off UAC to install an app, then turn it back on.  It is *very different* than giving a user admin privileges to install a program.

So, if this server is already doing anything important, leave it alone and put up with the UAC warnings. As Bart's answer mentioned and I will repeat, you should not be regularly logged into a production server other than to manage that server, and then only if it really can't be done from a client with the tools installed.

Comment: It seems like the consensus in the answers to the linked question is that turning UAC off **is** a bad idea.  Also, you should clarify why it is that turning UAC off might break applications -- specifically, filesystem and registry virtualization [is not active](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Criticism) when UAC is off, but that's more likely to reset a user's configuration of an app than it is to break the entire app's installation.  Other than UAC virtualization, there's no "central things in the OS" that are changed by enabling/disabling UAC.